# How to calculate a root node in a Merkle Patricia tree?

Tags: yellow-paper, state-trie

I'm trying to understand a Merkle Patricia tree. 
For example there are two accounts:
x00: {balance: 1}
x01: {balance: 2}

I can't understand how to begin building my trie.
RLP and HP encoding are known, but what is the root node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a pseudo-code example:

```
x00: {balance: 1}
x01: {balance: 2}
x02: {balance: 3}
x03: {balance: 4}
```

You calculate the first-level nodes:

```
hashOf("x00: {balance: 1}", "x01: {balance: 2}") -> node1 0x1234 
hashOf("x02: {balance: 3}", "x04: {balance: 3}") -> node2 0x5476
```

You then calculate the second-level node(s):

```
hashOf("node1 0x1234", "node2 0x5476") -> node3 0x3981
```

`node3`, with the value of `0x3981`, is your root node.

Comment: Are sure you are explaining Merkle Patricia Tree? It looks like classic Merkle tree

Comment: The pseudo-code I wrote describes both of them. A Patricia tree will provide storage savings because, unlike in my example, the address space of Ethereum's state is full of holes.